# How to serve multiple container using bitnami nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, bitnami

I have containers in one server:

1. web-zamrud, api-zamrud and db-zamrud, all of them using docker bridge named zamrud-network
2. web-berlian, api-berlian and db-berlian, all of them using docker bridge named berlian-network
3. nginx container to serve web-zamrud and web-berlian.

Below is zamrud containers docker-compose

```yaml
services:
  api-zamrud:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/zamrud/zamrudapi
    container_name: api-zamrud
    networks:
      - zamrud-network

  web-zamrud:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/zamrud/zamrudweb
    container_name: web-zamrud
    networks:
      - zamrud-network

networks:
  zamrud-network:
    external: true
```

Below is berlian container docker-compose

```yaml
services:
  api-berlian:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/berlian/berlianapi
    container_name: api-berlian
    networks:
      - berlian-network

  web-berlian:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/berlian/berlianweb
    container_name: web-berlian
    networks:
      - berlian-network

networks:
  berlian-network:
    external: true
```

Below is bitnami nginx docker compose file

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/nginx:1.21
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./conf/zamrud.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/zamrud.conf:ro
      - ./conf/berlian.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/berlian.conf:ro
    networks:
      - zamrud-network
      - berlian-network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Below is zamrud.conf

```yaml
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name zamrud.com www.zamrud.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://web-zamrud;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api {
      rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://api-zamrud:5000;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Below is berlian.conf

```yaml
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name berlian.com www.berlian.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://web-berlian;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api {
      rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://api-berlian:5000;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

If I try to access **[www.zamrud.com](http://www.zamrud.com)**, the content of website is properly displayed.

But if I try to access **[www.berlian.com](http://www.berlian.com)**, it show content of **[www.zamrud.com](http://www.zamrud.com)**.

Am I missing configuration in nginx?

Comment: please share the compose file or the `docker run` commands and config for the two services

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I have added docker-compose for zamrud and berlian container, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone face same problem, what I did is make the bitnami nginx container down

```
docker-compose down
```

and then up the bitnami nginx container again

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Note:

> file name for bitnami nginx docker-compose is docker-compose.yaml

> I run the docker down and up in the same folder as docker-compose.yaml